# What is the better approach to compare a collection with another (architecturely speaking)?

Tags: .net, oop, ienumerable, equals, icollection

Here's an example of the architecture approach I favorited as for now:

```
public abstract class CollectionComparer {
    public virtual SetEqual(IEnumerable enum1, IEnumerable enum2) {
        if(enum1== null && enum2== null)
            return true;

        if(enum1== null && !(enum2== null))
            return false;

        if(!(enum1== null) && enum2== null)
            return false;

        if(enum1.GetType().DeclaringType != enum2.GetType().DeclaringType)
            return false;

        var col1 = (from e in enum1 select e).ToList()
        var col2 = (from e in enum2 select e).ToList()

        if(col1.Count != col2.Count)
            return false;           

        foreach (element in col1)
            if(!col2.Contains(element))
                return false;

        foreach (element in col2)
            if(!col1.Contains(element))
                return false;

        return true; 
    }
}

public interface IProduct {
    ...
}

public interface IOrder {
    ...
    ICustomer Customer { get; }
    ICollection<IProduct> Products { get; }
}

public interface ICustomer {
    ...
    ICollection<IOrder> Orders { get; }
}

public internal Order : CollectionComparer, IOrder {
    #region IOrder interface implementation
    ...
    #endregion
}

public internal Customer : CollectionComparer, ICustomer {
    #region ICustomer interface implementation
    ...
    #endregion
}
```

Would this CollectionComparer abstract class approach be considered a good practice for collection comparison for an equivalent to object.Equals() applied to a collections?

Comment: Thanks to both Daniel A. White and "No Returns No Refunds" for these very excellent answers! Unfortunately, I can set only one answer as THE answer. Considering my first objective of determining whether collection had an equality comparer, Daniel A. White's answer is the best. Sorry No Returns No Refunds!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you seen this: `SequenceEqual`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348567.aspx

Comment: @Ram: Then perhaps my question has been useful, if it was just to learn about this SequenceEqual() method? ;P I'm kidding!

Comment: @Will: OK Will, +1 for your question too !!

Comment: @Ram: Thanks for your upvote! This is appreciated, really! Hope I can help you out someday onto one of your future questions! Have a nice day! =)

Answer (score 2):

How about implementing IComparable and calling it recursively for each item and each item property?  There's already a well-defined interface to compare objects.  Is there some reason you don't want to/can't use it?

Comment: Honestly? Ignorance! =P I have yet never ever used the IComparable interface. I guess I shall take an eye out to it. =)

Comment: `IComparable` is used internally by string and numeric types for sorting.

Comment: Thanks Daniel A. White for this information. I like to learn such information on how it works under the hood.

Comment: If you implement `IComparable`, your objects in a collection can easily be sorted, too.

Comment: This offers a great advantage then! Thanks Daniel!